# Sql - Filtering on certain category

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I am trying to write sql that would give me count of unique devices which appeared in category 'blue' and 'red' but not in any other category.

Below is my simple example. Answer for this question would be 3 devices (device 1, 2, 5).

If anyone could give me a tip, I would much appreciated. Thank you.

```
 device | category 
--------+----------
      1 | blue
      2 | red
      3 | black
      4 | yellow
      4 | blue
      5 | red
      5 | blue
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`bool_and():`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html)

```
with my_table(device, category) as (
values 
    (1, 'blue'),
    (2, 'red'),
    (3, 'black'),
    (4, 'yellow'),
    (4, 'blue'),
    (5, 'red'),
    (5, 'blue')
)

select device, bool_and(category in ('red', 'blue'))
from my_table
group by device
order by device;

 device | bool_and 
--------+----------
      1 | t
      2 | t
      3 | f
      4 | f
      5 | t
(5 rows)
```

Your query may look like this:

```
select device
from my_table
group by device
having bool_and(category in ('red', 'blue'))
order by device;
```

Comment: Hi gyus, thank you so much for helping me so quickly! bool_and() solved my problem perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to join your table to an aggregation query which identifies matching devices.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT Device
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Device
    HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN category NOT IN ('blue', 'red') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
)

SELECT t1.Device, t1.Category
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN cte t2
    ON t1.Device = t2.Device;
```

We can also use `SUM` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT Device, category
FROM
(
    SELECT Device, category,
        SUM(CASE WHEN category NOT IN ('blue', 'red') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER
            (PARTITION BY Device) color_sum
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE color_sum = 0;
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct device from Test
where category in ('blue','red')
except
select distinct device from Test
where category in (select distinct category from test
                     where category not in ('blue','red'))
```

or if you need count:

```
select count(*)
from
(select distinct device from Test
where category in ('blue','red')
except
select distinct device from Test
where category in (select distinct category from test
                     where category not in ('blue','red'))) a
```